# Hide Enter key from numeric keyboard

Tags: android, kotlin

I am creating a pin feature for our app that works perfectly but the UI person wants the enter key or "checkmark" key as they call it gone. Is this possible?
I have tried a few things I found online but nothing changes. I tried maxLine = 1 and imeOptions.

Here is my current XML for the edit text

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etPinNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
    android:inputType="numberPassword"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:maxLength="4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvcreatePinTxt"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

[image: Can it be hidden?]

Answer (score 0):

To show another things instead `enter` or  `done` key you can show `search` by using `android:imeOptions="actionSearch"` in `EditText` element .

Or to do a specific action by `done` key of your provided xml code you can use below code to your Activity -

```
 EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPinNumber);
    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
@Override
   public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    boolean handled = false;
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
        //TODO //do your job
        Toast.makeText(Main4Activity.this,"Not applied",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        handled = true;
    }
    return handled;
}
});
```

Comment: is it possible to hide it altogether?

Comment: please check 1st option of my answer

Comment: that is to change it but not hide it unfortunately

Comment: please check https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style#Action

Comment: Then you may build your own customize keyboard https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.java

Comment: Unfortunately we want to use all native android stuff and not use custom stuff.  Thank you for your help